# Message: element not visible when tring to click a checkbox through Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors

I am trying to automate one part of my project I've been working on.
This part of the project should enter a page and get a randomly generated key.
To get the key it goes to the web-page, login and then presses some buttons to get the new key.
I've been using Selenium with Chrome driver to do so.

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
```

The problem started when I had to check some checkboxes.

This is how the page looks like:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/4GHaD.jpg

Source file looks like its JavaScript rendered.

What I've tried so far:
Getting it by id:

```
checkbox = label.find_element_by_id("agreed")
checkbox.click()
```

Getting it by XPath:

```
checkbox = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="agreed"]')
```

Both are giving me:

```
Message: element not visible
```

I've also tried waiting for it to be visible but it just waits and eventually gives me the following:

```
checkbox = WebDriverWait(driver, 3).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="agreed"]')))
checkbox.click()
```

Output:

```
Message:
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To click on the *checkbox* associated with the element with text as **I agree with the API Servive Agreement** instead of invoking `visibility_of_element_located()` you need to invoke **`element_to_be_clickable()`** and you can use either of the following solutions:

- `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "label[for='agreed']"))).click()
  ```
- `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//label[@for='agreed']"))).click()
  ```

Comment: I've just tried your method and it works, thank you!

Comment: nice answer with explanation.

Answer (score 2):

You should check in console if that id is returning only one element or more then one.
Sometimes more then one elements are present in DOM for same id or selector.
In which one is hidden and one is visible. you have to find the visible one and click on it.
Also check if that element is not present in an iframe.

In console write below lines to see the number of elements for this id :

```
$x("//*[@id='agreed']")
```

Hope that helps you.

Comment: I've checked if there are other elements with the same id with jqury and there arent any besides that https://imgur.com/DFAjmxx. Also checked for jframes and there aren't any

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176251/discussion-between-dangi13-and-paul).

Answer (score 1):

Always have in mind using `driver.implicitly_wait(X)` where X is a number of seconds to make your driver to automatically retry when an element is not found. Besides browser automation have you tried capturing the requests? In similar cases I've managed to automate the post request using cookies from the session. If you are unlucky and there's session timeout after a while you can use your selenium script to renew your cookies and continue with automated requests.

Comment: I will be looking into this method later. Maybe it will be better since selenium is kinda slow. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: I worked on a similar data gathering script like 2 weeks ago. You will see a huge speed bump by replicating the requests instead of browser emulation. Afterwards if your needs are too high start experimenting with multithreading your requests. I managed to get about 8 replies per second but it's a server issue. If the server can handle the load with ie 25 threads and be stable work with it.